# Excel VBA Search for a value in a column and copy row to new sheet for all matching values

Tags: vba, excel, copy

What it is supposed to do is compare a name from column G, find that name in column E and if there is a match, copy all to a new sheet. Right now the code searches for a value called Mail box, each time it finds it in range of the column E it copies the whole row to a new sheet2.

I am capable of transforming the code that instead of searching for Mail box it searches for a value in a cell G1, yet I would need the code to do it several times again for a value in row G2, G3, G4, G5...G20.

```
Sub SearchForString()

   Dim LSearchRow As Integer
   Dim LCopyToRow As Integer

   On Error GoTo Err_Execute

   'Start search in row 4
   LSearchRow = 4

   'Start copying data to row 2 in Sheet2 (row counter variable)
   LCopyToRow = 2

   While Len(Range("A" & CStr(LSearchRow)).Value) > 0

      'If value in column E = "Mail Box", copy entire row to Sheet2
      If Range("E" & CStr(LSearchRow)).Value = "Mail Box" Then

         'Select row in Sheet1 to copy
         Rows(CStr(LSearchRow) & ":" & CStr(LSearchRow)).Select
         Selection.Copy

         'Paste row into Sheet2 in next row
         Sheets("Sheet2").Select
         Rows(CStr(LCopyToRow) & ":" & CStr(LCopyToRow)).Select
         ActiveSheet.Paste

         'Move counter to next row
         LCopyToRow = LCopyToRow + 1

         'Go back to Sheet1 to continue searching
         Sheets("Sheet1").Select

      End If

      LSearchRow = LSearchRow + 1

   Wend

   'Position on cell A3
   Application.CutCopyMode = False
   Range("A3").Select

   MsgBox "All matching data has been copied."

   Exit Sub

Err_Execute:
   MsgBox "An error occurred."

End Sub
```

Comment: Your question is not clear. Do you understand what your posted code does? If so, please outline where in the code the behaviour is not what you expect / desire. If you don't understand it, don't run it; running code you can't read can cause malicious behaviour and could leave you unable to progress if your data changes enough that your macros no longer work the way you want.

Comment: Hi, Right now the code searches for a value called Mail box, each time it finds it in range of the column E it copies the whole row to a new sheet2. I am capable of transforming the code that instead of searching for Mail box it searches for a value in a cell G1, yet I would need the code to do it several times again for a value in row G2, G3, G4, G5...G20. Thank You

Comment: I have edited your question to include your clarifications; see my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your comment, it seems you just want to see if any cell in column E matches any cell in Column G, and then perform your copying. You can achieve this as follows:

```
  'If value in column E = Matches anything in column G, copy entire row to Sheet2
  Dim searchTerm As String
  For i = 1 To 20
      searchTerm = Range("G" & i).Text
      If Range("E" & CStr(LSearchRow)).Value = searchTerm Then

         'Select row in Sheet1 to copy
         Rows(CStr(LSearchRow) & ":" & CStr(LSearchRow)).Select
         Selection.Copy

         'Paste row into Sheet2 in next row
         Sheets("Sheet2").Select
         Rows(CStr(LCopyToRow) & ":" & CStr(LCopyToRow)).Select
         ActiveSheet.Paste

         'Move counter to next row
         LCopyToRow = LCopyToRow + 1

         'Go back to Sheet1 to continue searching
         Sheets("Sheet1").Select

      End If
Next i
```

This simply loops through G1:G20, picks up each value of G there, and for each row of E (as looped with your While loop), it checks for each value of G and then performs the copying.

Comment: Hi Grade. Thank You for being patient with me. Yet when I try running the code you provided I always end up with an error. I assumed I need to paste your code instead of the part between the while wend part yet it doesn't work either. Could You please paste whole your code from sub to end sub. Thanks

Comment: @Jstsmtle this code does *instead of* the `While...Wend` block. Not *between*, but fully replace it. When implemented, you will not have a `While` or a `Wend` statement in your code at all.

Comment: It would help if you supplied the code you already tried and what you're already using. What you are looking for can be done with an for each loop and if statements. You could try looking those up, they contain the "loop" logic you are looking for