# Copy Row based on changing cell value

Tags: vba, excel

I keep coming across this [code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32138287/excel-vba-search-for-a-value-in-a-column-and-copy-row-to-new-sheet-for-all-match) when searching for a way to copy a row based on a value in a column. The issue I'm running into is that I am not using the same phrase every single time I want to run the table. I'd like it to change what it copies based on what is in cell B18 versus using the same value every time. I linked the macro that I've been seeing above, but the specific lines of code are:

```
If Range("E" & CStr(LSearchRow)).Value = "Mail Box" Then
   Rows(CStr(LSearchRow) & ":" & CStr(LSearchRow)).Select
     Selection.Copy
```

Instead of "Mail Box" I'd like to use the contents of cell B18 on sheet "Dashboard"

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Try this. Note that `Select` not needed. You should really add a sheet reference to the first range too and the `Rows`.

```
If Range("E" & CStr(LSearchRow)).Value = sheets("Dashboard").Range("B18").Value Then
   Rows(CStr(LSearchRow) & ":" & CStr(LSearchRow)).Copy
```

Comment: Thanks @Jeeped, amended.